# Why does biber segfault using a macro in the author field?

Tags: biblatex, biber

Before I updated my TexLive2018 (Win7-64bit, Texstudio) 5 minutes ago, the following code compiled fine:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{bib.bib}
@book{authorA20,
    author = {Author, A.},
    translator = {Translator, A.},
    title = {These and that},
    subtitle = {Nothing special},
    volume = 1,
    location = {Here and there},
    publisher = {Who knows},
    year = {2020},
    isbn = {978-0-000-00000-2},
}
@book{buthorB22,
    author = {\authorSn, \authorGivenname},
    shorthand = {\volTwoShorthand},
    translator = {\volTwoTranslator},
    title = {\volTwoTitle},
    subtitle = {\volTwoSubtitle},
    volume = {\volTwoNumber},
    location = {\volTwoLocation},
    publisher = {\volTwoPublisher},
    year = {\volTwoYear},
    isbn = {\volTwoIsbn},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{xstring} %<- provides StrLeft/-Right (s. below)
\newcommand{\authorSn}{Buthor}
\newcommand{\authorGivenname}{B.}
\newcommand{\volTwoTranslator}{Translator, B.}
\newcommand{\volTwoTitle}{These and that}
\newcommand{\volTwoSubtitle}{Nothing special}
\newcommand{\volTwoNumber}{2}
\newcommand{\volTwoLocation}{Here and there}
\newcommand{\volTwoPublisher}{Who knows}
\newcommand{\volTwoYear}{2022}
\newcommand{\volTwoShorthand}{\StrLeft{\authorSn}{3}%
    \StrRight{\volTwoYear}{2}}

\newcommand{\volTwoIsbn}{978-1-111-11111-1}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}

\begin{document}

Wow \cite{authorA20}!

Crazy \cite{buthorB22}!

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

After the update, biber 2.12 reproducible segfaults. I don't know exactly what biber version I've used before (my previous updated was some time ago, in this summer).

The problematic field seems to be `author = {\authorSn, \authorGivenname}`. If I replace this field using hard coded values, e.g. `author = {Bauthor, B.}` the compilation succeeds, with obvious - in my opinion harmless - warnings.

Running `biber --tool --validate-datamodel bib.bib` SEGV, too.

Comment: You'll have to wait for someone more knowledgeable to explain what has changed for this new behavior. But, in the meantime, you could try `author = {\relax\authorSn, \relax\authorGivenname}`. You will still continue to receive warnings on your `year` and `isbn` fields though.

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks a lot for this workaround - seems to work fine. Now I'm  completely relaxed. ;-)

Comment: Well, don't get too comfy. You are indeed stretching what biber expects there. As you see, even when it runs, sorting seems wrong. Do you have a strong reason to use this?

Comment: Reason: Consistency. My project[s] usually consist of various related documents. Imagine a book, its cover and one or more relating letters (all are standalone documents, using the same settings).

Comment: Well, that's a good requirement in general, I concur. But usually there's more than one way to achieve it. You could invert the logic here, you could call the data from the bibentry to fill in your macros, and then use them in the other places you need. If you think that might be an alternative, extend your MWE to show some use cases of the macros elsewhere, and I see what can do.

Comment: how can biber possibly sort the bibliography without having access to the names? (it shouldn't segfault of course but it can't work)

Comment: There are probably much better ways to do what you want (although your exact use case isn't clear from the question.) Perhaps things like string variables in `bibtex` files might interest you along with the `crossref`, `xref`, and `related` fields. `\DeclareSourcemap` from `biblatex` could also prove useful and maybe even the various `<namepart>inits` option for `biblatex`.

Comment: @gusbrs The question primary deals with the segfault. The use case - questionable or not - does not matter, here. I'll open a new question regarding how to query bibentries (could you please tell me where I can find some documentation regarding your suggestion? A quick search lead me to biblatex manual section 3.10 "Entry Querying Commands", but that seems not very helpful) Thx!

Comment: Another workaround may be to define your macro at your editor level and have it already expanded in your .bib file. Look at abbrevs section of your editor.

Comment: @sztruks thanks for the idea - sounds easy, but I don't want to be introduce a dependency regarding the editor[s] I use.

Comment: I'd also like to suggest you 'invert the logic': You can use the commands from §3.8.7 *Low-level Commands* to query all the data from the `.bib` directly. If it is important that this one entry's data be visible in the `.tex` file directly you could work with `filecontents` or a separate `.bib` file that only contains this special entry.

Comment: @moewe thanks a lot for your answer and the suggestion towards low level commands: `\newcommand{\myName}{\citename{authorA20}{author}}` works fine - I'll ask a new question if I need to know more details.

Comment: @lAtExFaN I see moewe already has got you covered with what you asked me. :)

Comment: @gusbrs yes, thanks to all. I decided to use a filecontents-2ndbibfile-solution.

Comment: @lAtExFaN Nice, I think it is a wise option. You will be better served than in your previous setup. Still, a report at biber's issue tracker, as suggested by moewe, would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interestingly on my machine I can reproduce the segfault (I don't get any error report, Biber just dies and does not write a `.bbl`) in about 70% of runs, while the other 30% compile just fine (with slightly weird data in the `.bbl`: `family={\volTwoTranslator}, familyi={r\bibinitperiod}`).

You can and should probably report this at https://github.com/plk/biber/issues (Stackexchange is not a bug tracker), but it might turn out that there is no good way to solve this in Biber. Biber relies on the Perl module [Text::BibTeX](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::BibTeX), which in term delegates its work to the C library `btparse`. Catching errors (especially segfaults) from that module sometimes proves a little difficult.

In this case it seems that the code to parse names, in particular the code that deals with name initials, is ill-equipped to deal with a name that consists only of macros. Remember that Biber does not know LaTeX, which means that it does not expand/unpack macro definitions (except in very specific, hard-coded cases). At the same time Biber needs access to the proper string values of fields to do its job: Sorting can only be performed as expected if Biber really knows the expansion of the macros and not just their name. And – this is the issue here – initials can only be generated from names if their string values are known.

There are two workaround that I can think of.

1. As mentioned by [gusbrs](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/105447/gusbrs) [in the comments already](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461746/why-does-biber-segfault-using-a-macro-in-the-author-field#comment1161343_461746), use `\relax` in the `author` field: `\relax` can be used as a marker for BibTeX/`btparse` in names to tell it to parse the current bit of the name differently.

   ```
   author = {\relax\authorSn, \relax\authorGivenname},
   ```

   compiles to

   ```
   family={\relax\authorSn},
   familyi={\\bibinitperiod},
   given={\relax\authorGivenname},
   giveni={\\bibinitperiod}}}%
   ```

   which is still wrong, but at least does not let Biber die.

   BibTeX treats groups in names that start with a control sequence as one character, which means that `{\'E}cole` would be abbreviated as `{\'E}` and not as `{\'}` or `{E}` or something else. In BibTeX this allows for the neat trick `{\relax Th}omas` to get "Th." as name initial (this no longer works in Biber).
2. You can turn off the calculation of initials by giving them yourself with the extended name format.

   ```
   author = {family={\authorSn}, given={\authorGivenname},
             family-i={\authorSn}, given-i={\authorGivenname}},
   ```

   compiles to

   ```
   family={\authorSn},
   familyi={\authorSn\bibinitperiod},
   given={\authorGivenname},
   giveni={\authorGivenname\bibinitperiod}}}%
   ```

   still not great, but better than nothing.

   Of course you could give the *real* initials explicitly if you determine them yourself beforehand.